# problems with ubiquity/success_command Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: automation, ubuntu-14.04, ubiquity

I want to automate the Ubuntu installation (a fully unattended installation without questions). I also want to run a script right after the installation is finished.

What I did is that I managed to have a fully unattended Ubuntu installation. I am doing this by providing a pre-seed file and using boot parameters to preseed the questions that are asked before the preseed file is loaded. The installation went okay but the problem lies with running the script right after the installation completion. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version thus I am not using the late command as I have read that it won't be noticed by the installer. Instead, I am using the Ubiquity/success_command. I have the following code at the end of my pre-seed file.

```
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
mkdir /target/dev-master/; \ 
cp -r /cdrom/dev-master/* /target/dev-master/; \ 
chroot /target bash /dev-master/SCRIPT;
```

The problem is nothing happens. I think the command went unnoticed as well.

I am not sure if I am approaching the problem correctly.

What am I doing wrong ?

Is there any other alternatives that might provide the desired result ? Any help would be appreciated and thanks.